# I am unable to run the .bat file(TestNG script) via Jenkins, Firefox browser 56.0. Unable to launch browser too

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Below is error while running testng.xml :

```
Started by user Vaibhav Singh
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace C:/Users/vaibhavsi/eclipse-workspace/Thomas Cook
No emails were triggered.
[Thomas Cook] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins8880098643415850948.bat

C:\Users\vaibhavsi\eclipse-workspace\Thomas Cook>Forex.bat

C:\Users\vaibhavsi\eclipse-workspace\Thomas Cook>cd C:\Users\vaibhavsi\eclipse-workspace\Thomas Cook 

C:\Users\vaibhavsi\eclipse-workspace\Thomas Cook>set projectpath=C:\Users\vaibhavsi\eclipse-workspace\Thomas Cook 

C:\Users\vaibhavsi\eclipse-workspace\Thomas Cook>set classpath=C:\Users\vaibhavsi\eclipse-workspace\Thomas Cook\bin;C:\Users\vaibhavsi\eclipse-workspace\Thomas Cook\lib\* 

C:\Users\vaibhavsi\eclipse-workspace\Thomas Cook>java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml" 
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\vaibhavsi\eclipse-workspace\Thomas Cook\testng.xml

WebBrowser open
1507790139603   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.18.0
1507790139621   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:10520
1507790140325   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
1507790142393   addons.xpi  WARN    Error parsing extensions state: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [amIAddonManagerStartup.readStartupData]"  nsresult: "0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm :: loadExtensionState :: line 1554"  data: no] Stack trace: loadExtensionState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1554 < getInstallState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1589 < checkForChanges()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:3109 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:2188 < callProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:269 < _startProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:739 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:906 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3090 < observe()@jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/omni.ja!/components/addonManager.js:65
1507790143573   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x24001F,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv
```

Please look into same.

Comment: You would need to add more information. Just the console output doesnt help in anyway. Please specify what version of selenium, firefox browser, geckodriver (from the console it looks like you are using 0.18.0) are you working with, along with sample code of how your browser instantiation looks like.

Comment: Sure, Will add code for the same and other details Selenium: 2017 Oxygen, Gecko driver: 0.18.0, FF - 56.0

Comment: Same is working fine now, thanks a ton.